# Windows Server 2012 Apache XAMPP

Tags: php, sql, windows-server-2012, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to get the MySQL to run with XAMPP. But I keep getting the following errors :

```
2015-03-24 08:46:04 3624 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-03-24 08:46:04 2c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-03-24 08:46:04 3624 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-03-24 08:46:04 3624 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-03-24 08:46:04 3624 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-03-24 08:46:04 3624 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-03-24 08:46:04 3624 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-03-24 08:46:04 3624 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-03-24 08:46:04 3624 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-03-24 08:46:04 3624 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-03-24 08:46:04 3624 [ERROR] InnoDB: C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
2015-03-24 08:46:04 3624 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
2015-03-24 08:46:04 3624 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2015-03-24 08:46:04 3624 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-03-24 08:46:04 3624 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2015-03-24 08:46:04 3624 [ERROR] Aborting
```

**Note**

I do have IIS and I also tried to run the webserver without installing xampp, but because I couldnt get access to the mssql database wich is already installed here I kind of gave up and tried to install xampp ...

I will also post my other error message :

```
Array ([0 ] = > Array ([0 ] = > 28000 [ SQLSTATE ] = > 28000 [ 1] = > 18456 [code ] = > 18456 [2 ] = > [ Microsoft] [ODBC Driver for SQL Server 11 ] [ SQL server] Login failed for user ' username ' . [message ] = > [ Microsoft] [ODBC Driver for SQL server 11 ] [ SQL server] Login failed for user ' username ' . ) [1 ] = > Array ([0 ] = > 28000 [ SQLSTATE ] = > 28000 [ 1] = > 18456 [code ] = > 18456 [2 ] = > [ Microsoft] [ODBC Driver for SQL server 11 ] [ SQL server] Login failed for user ' FHGA / hgaadmin ' . [message ] = > [ Microsoft] [ODBC Driver for SQL server 11 ] [ SQL server] Login failed for user ' username ' . ) )
```

To specify my question :

I need help in either setting up the MYSQL in XAMPP ,or getting rid of the second error message which occus when I try to access the SQL DB with sqlsrv method